# Web Application Proxy + Azure WebRole

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, webproxy

I am using Azure PAAS. All database servers, application servers and proxy servers are with in my virtual network.

How to setup web application proxy for azure web role?

Comment: What have you tried? Give us something to work on. Your question is too broad. May be checking the Azure Docs will help? :/

Comment: What do you want, to connect to other network (your on premise network)?

Answer (score 1):

Change webrole endpoint to Localhost and enable Firewall rule **Http trafic in**. then site can access form proxy server.

Using web application proxy setup https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn383650.aspx we can configure proxy for web role.